# iOS FBSDKCoreKit "unaligned size for architecture arm 64"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0, ios8.3

Some background information,  I included FBSDKCoreKit.framework in xcode version 6.3.1 (Yosemite).
I'm getting this error message when I try to load the application into a mobile phone.

Error message:
FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata.o), load command #1 has a unaligned size for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

However I don't get this error when I tried to load the application into a mobile phone in xcode 6.2 (Mavericks).

Anyone experienced in this?

Comment: If any of you guys come across this issue, do try it on another mac. I managed to get it working by loading the project into another mac with xcode 6.3.2 (Yosemite). Very weird issue.